# XPages goto nextEntry in While loop

Tags: while-loop, xpages

I get documents from view. I would like to goto directly to a line just like "GOTO" command in Lotusscript;
is it possible with JavaScript?

```
var vec:NotesViewEntryCollection = database.getView("viewName").getAllEntries();
var entry:NotesViewEntry = vec.getLastEntry();
while (entry != null) 
{
        var subject:string = entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("subject");
        if (subject=="Title1")
        {
            goto prevEntry; 
        }
        if (subject=="Title2")
        {
            goto prevEntry; 
        }
        if (subject=="Title3")
        {
            //do something here...;
        }
    //prevEntry;
        var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = vec.getPrevEntry(entry);
        entry.recycle();
        entry = tmpentry;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good for your code that JavaScript has no **goto**.

Use [continue](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) instead to leave current iteration in a loop and to continue with the next iteration.

```js
var vec:NotesViewEntryCollection = database.getView("viewName").getAllEntries();
var entry:NotesViewEntry = vec.getLastEntry();

var nextEntry = function() {
    var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = vec.getPrevEntry(entry);
    entry.recycle();
    entry = tmpentry;
    return entry != null;
}

if (entry != null) { 
    do {
        var subject:string = entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("subject");
        if (subject=="Title1") {
            //do 1...;
            continue; 
        }
        if (subject=="Title2") {
            //do 2...;
        }
        //do 3...;
    } while (nextEntry())
}
```

If subject is "Title1" then it will `//do 1...`.
If subject is "Title2" then it will `//do 2...` and  `//do 3...`.

Answer (score 2):

That code can be reduced to:

```
var vec:NotesViewEntryCollection = database.getView("viewName").getAllEntries();
var entry:NotesViewEntry = vec.getLastEntry();
while (entry != null) 
{
    var subject:string = entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("subject");
    if (subject=="Title3") {
        //do something here...;
    }
    //prevEntry;
    var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = vec.getPrevEntry(entry);
    entry.recycle();
    entry = tmpentry;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your if statement.
if("Title3".equals(subject){
//do Something
}
 go on withe code and to the next entry